# "percentile" or "centile"?

Tags: terminology

I know that both terms exist but I wonder which one would/should be considered (more) correct? Percentile seems an oddball as we also use quantile, decile, quartile, but never perdecile etc.

Comment: Don't Google ngrams indicate idiomaticity? Dictionaries add usage notes / caveats?

Comment: Please include an example sentence - https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info

Answer (score 2):

According to Stuart and Ord (Kendall's Advanced Theory of Statistics, Fifth Edition, Vol 1, 1987), *percentile* (and *quartile*) were terms coined by the creative, innovative and authoritative statistician (amongst many other things) Sir Francis Galton.

Coming from a creative and formative intellect, his term endured in the face of the more consistent term *centile*, which as you say, parallels *quartile*, *decile* and others. Both are correct and both seem widely understood in the statistical literature.

Answer (score 1):

Both of them are correct and have the same meaning.

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/centile) defines *centile* as:

> noun
>
> *(not in technical use)* a percentile.

According to [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=26&smoothing=3&content=centile%2Cpercentile&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccentile%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpercentile%3B%2Cc0), **percentile** is much more prevalent.
[image: Centile and percentile]

Answer (score 1):

Which is more correct would depend on style more than anything else.

In theory, you could make a case that [*cent*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cent) has more senses than [*percent*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/percent), and, therefore, despite [*centile*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/centile) simply being listed as meaning [*percentile*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/percentile) by some dictionaries, argue for *centile* actually meaning something different than *percentile* in the right situation.

But I think that would be a highly uncommon situation, and perhaps even one that was contrived just to make a point. Practically speaking, they mean the same thing.

The choice of which to use is subjective.

---

As for the mention of *perdecile*, every word that's been mentioned in the question except for that one comes from an existing base word to which the suffix **-ile** has been added:

> [Merriam-Webster]
> *adjective suffix*
> : tending to or capable of
> // contract*ile*
> *noun suffix*
> : segment of a (specified) size in a frequency distribution
> // dec*ile*

There is no *perdec**ile***, because there is no such word as *perdec*.

Although we have *percent*, which came from *per cent*, and the Latin *per centum*, I'm not aware of any common use of *per dec* from which *perdec* would originate and to which *-ile* would be added.

So using the lack of *perdecile* as the basis for deciding between *percentile* and *centile* is not the right analogy.